# How should I implement a Mahalanobis distance function in Java?

Tags: java, 3d, matrix, distance, covariance

I am working on a project in java and have two 2d int arrays both 10x15. I want to convert the [Mahalanobis distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) between them. They are grouped in categories along the x axis of the array (size 10). I understand that you must find the mean value in these groups and redistribute the data so that it is centered. My problem now is generating the covariance matrix necessary for calculation. If anyone knows a  good way to do this or point to a useful guide that can step me through the process in 3D it would be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) matrix contains the expected relationship between any two variables.  Given a statistical distribution on a vector `x`, with statistical mean `avg`:

```
covariance(i,j) = expected value of [ (x[i] - avg[i])(x[j] - avg[j]) ]
```

Given a statistical set of `N` vectors `v_1 ... v_N`, with mean vector `avg`, you can estimate the covariance of the distribution they were taken from as follows:

```
sample_covariance(i,j) = sum[for k=1..N]( (v_k[i] - avg[i])*(v_k[j] - avg[j]) ) / (N-1)
```

This last is the covariance matrix you're looking for.  I recommend you also read the wiki link above.

Comment: Thanks for the help. For any future people out there looking to do this, there is a nice Java library called Colt that has a whole set of functions for manipulating matrices.